Import data from Excel into array without looping (Epplus c#)
Newbie here (first question!). I'm trying to find the quickest way to import a large amount of data from an excel worksheet into a c# array.
In VBA, this is very simple (and fast). e.g.:
arr_data_input_table = wkbkInput_data_file.Worksheets("data").Range("a1:k190000").Value2
In c#, I'm using EPPlus but have only found examples that involve looping round each row/column to import the data.
Is there any equivalent code using EPPlus and c# to do what the VBA code above does?
I.e. Is there a way to use Epplus to import data from excel without looping?
I've done some speed tests and on a cell range of 190,000 rows and 9 columns, Epplus takes ~3.9 seconds to loop round the data.
In VBA, the line of code above takes 0.117 seconds (so ~35 times faster).
Am I missing something or should I just accept the slower data import speed?
Many thanks for any help.
